# Send radiobutton value via form method Link

Tags: html

I currently have a dropdown in a HTML form which succesfully sends the content of each option via Link:

```
<form action="url.html" method="LINK">

Amount:<input name="Amount" type="text"/>

Invoice number<input name="ID" type="text"/>

Payment method:

<select name="Paymethod">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
<option>F</option>
<option>G</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" value="Proceed"/>

</form>
```

When filling in for example 10, 123 and A and press Proceed, the page is send to url.html?Amount=10&ID=123&Paymethod=A

I'd like to replace the dropdown with radiobuttons, but not sure how to achieve this. So far I have this:

```
Payment method:
<input type="radio" name="Paymethod" checked>iDeal<br>
<input type="radio" name="Paymethod">Paypal<br>
```

However, "&Paymethod=iDeal" is not included in the URL.

Any thoughts?

**Solution thanks to Pekka, add "value":**

```
<input type="radio" name="Betaalwijze" value="ideal" checked>iDeal<br>
<input type="radio" name="Betaalwijze" value="paypal">Paypal<br>
```

Comment: Do you put these fields inside form or outside? Also there is only `POST` and `GET` methods, there is no `LINK` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method

Comment: Radiobuttons need a `value` property.

Comment: thanks Pekka thats it

Answer (score 0):

Each radio button should have the same `name` attribute and a value applied to each.

The selected radiobutton value will then be passed as part of the form post.

```
<input type="radio" name="Paymethod" value="A" />
<input type="radio" name="Paymethod" value="B" />
```